# How can I resolve TintEditText after importing the Android Design Library?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-design-library

I added the following line to my `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

but now all the files that have this line:

```
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintEditText;
```

throw a 'cannot find symbol' error. What gives? I can remove the Android Design Library and it works again, but of course this is not a solution.

Comment: Why do you have an `import` statement for an `internal` class? That is not part of the public API for `appcompat-v7`.

Comment: Google added some public widgets... https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatEditText.html

Comment: Good point. I am picking this app up where another dev left off. Guess this is wrong.

Comment: @Selvin, this worked. If you make this an answer, I'll select it as best.

Comment: BTW, presumably your `build.gradle` `appcompat-v7` dependency is pulling in something like version 21. Adding `design:22.2.0` will upgrade the `appcompat-v7` dependency to version 22 through transitive dependencies. The fact that they renamed (and made public) `TintEditText` would explain your symptoms.

Comment: @CommonsWare, neat - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of api 21 you must subclass AppCompatEdit text. Same is true for all the supported widgets. Use AppCompat* to get tinting and other back supported functionality.

android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintEditText is an internal class of android and you can not use it as of support library update.